# Best search engines for scientific books

Tags: research-process, books

I'm wondering which are the best search engines for scientific books. I know google book, but here I'm not able to find books which contain the specified key words and published by a specific editor. E.g. key word "real-time system", editor "wiley".

Could you suggest me which are the best search engines to reach this goal please?

Comment: Not really an answer but one that I find very useful is the catalogue of the [_bibliothèque national de France_](https://catalogue.bnf.fr/index.do). The good thing is that if you cannot find a book elsewhere, they can send you a photocopy if you pay the copyright fees (about the price of the book). I did it this for a book which is out of print, and there was just one copy in all Italy but the library lost it.

Comment: Thank you @MassimoOrtolano

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of non-commercial meta-catalogs that cover the stock of various (often national) libraries. For example, Germany, Austria and Switzerland have a common cross-library interlibrary loan catalogue called "Karlsruher Virtueller Katalog". In the United States, there is the Catalogue of the Library of Congress, which probably has the largest coverage in the country. Italy has the "OPAC SBN" of the "Istituto Centrale per il Catalogo Unico".

In terms of coverage, meta cataloges like these represent the submerged part of the iceberg that Google Books only sees the tip of. However, only small parts, if any, of the inventory are accessible for full-text search.

The use of these catalogs is free of charge, but small fees are charged for checking out books or for ordering copies of book sections, journal articles, or other documents.

In general, it's always a good idea to talk to a librarian for particular queries or about search strategies.

Answer (score 1):

If it has to be a free one, I recommend [LENS](https://lens.org/).

Search for `real-time system`, then under "Publication Type", tick `book`, and under "Publisher", opt for `John Wiley & Sons, Inc`.

[Here are the 208 results](https://www.lens.org/lens/search/scholar/list?q=real-time%20system&p=0&n=10&s=_score&d=%2B&f=false&e=false&l=en&authorField=author&dateFilterField=publishedYear&orderBy=%2B_score&presentation=false&stemmed=true&useAuthorId=false&publicationType.must=book&publisher.must=John%20Wiley%20%26%20Sons,%20Inc.).

Other than that, there are commercial databases like *Web of Science* or *Scopus*. It is best to ask your university library whether they have a subscription to them.

Comment: Hello@ @anpami thank you very much for your reply. Can you tell me how to perform a search on scopus please? I tried to write the query DOCTYPE(bk) ALL(real-time systems) EDITOR(wiley) but Scopus doesn't find any book. I tried also with DOCTYPE(bk) ALL(real-time systems) EDITOR(John Wiley & Sons, Inc)

Comment: idem for DOCTYPE(bk) EDITOR(wiley) KEY(real-time systems)

Comment: I could try, but your question deviates so much from my response that I believe it would merit its own thread (rather than a response in the comments here).

Comment: ok, btw thank you for the answer. I'll upvote it

Comment: see the new question please https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/162251/doing-a-query-on-scopus