# Doing a query on Scopus

Tags: research-process, books, scopus

I'm trying to perform a specific query on Scopus. To be precise, I am looking for books from Wiley that are related to real time systems.

Maybe I did a mistake because there aren't results. The query I tried is:

`DOCTYPE(bk) EDITOR(wiley) KEY(real time systems)`

Could you tell me how to do it please?

Answer (score 2):

The `EDITOR()`-field searches for *editors*, i.e. (usually) human individuals who edit a volume.

You are looking, instead, for a book's publisher. The correct field would thus be labelled `BOOKPUB()`.

With the following query, I find 8 results:

`DOCTYPE ( "bk" )  AND  BOOKPUB ( "Wiley" )  AND  KEY ( "real time systems" )`

(Note that I added the operator `AND` between each field as well as quotation marks within the parentheses.)